# How to set the Ancesstor in button and what is that purpose?

Tags: wpf

I was set the mode FindAncestor and Ancestor Type as X:Type as DataGrid and set the ClickCommand to the path.Now,my question is why to set the FindAncestor and AncestorType what is the actual behavior in the button command.

Thanks

Comment: _I was set the mode FindAncestor_ ... _why to set the FindAncestor_ You set it but don't know why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following link on writing a good question and edit accordingly:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
FindAncestor and `AncestorType`
```

are used especially when for some reason , you can't access the datacontext of the window with your control.

Take this as example:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="DataGridColumnHeader"  >
        <ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Oggetto" Width="100" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.Selezione, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

DataGridHeader doesn't inherit the datacontext of the datagrid, so i had to use that sintaxt to take the datacontext from the ancestor and set the itemsource